# Local Inter-process Communication via TCP Sockets in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, ipc

I get an exception when doing this in one thread:

```cs
var listener = new TcpListener(new IPEndPoint("127.0.0.1", 3536));
listener.Start();
```

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): Address already in use

and this in another thread:

```cs
var client = new TcpClient(new IPEndPoint("127.0.0.1", 3536));
```

I know that I can't create two sockets on the same port, but I want one thing and the other receiving.

What I want to achieve is inter-process communication between a LOCAL C# and Python program. I've opted for sockets cause pipes work differently on Windows and Unix Systems and I wanted the possibility to outsource one program to another machine.

Edit: The TCP listener runs flawlessly when I remove

```cs
var client = new TcpClient(new IPEndPoint("127.0.0.1", 3536));
```

Edit2: I've had a

```cs
Thread.Sleep
```

on my main Thread. If I replace it with

```cs
while (!client.Connected) client.Connect(ipEndPoint)
Console.WriteLine(client.Connected) // this reaches
```

I don't currently know about data-transfer yet

Comment: There is no problem having a client and server running on the same machine.  The error means that there is likely *another* app running on your machine that is already using port 3536 for its own purposes (use `netstat` or equivalent tool to find out).  So try using a different port.  Otherwise, you could have the listener use port 0 instead to pick a random available port, and then advertise that port somewhere that the client can then discover and use it.

Comment: I can start a socket or listener on that port and it works when I just have the listener and connect to it via netcat

Comment: There may be easier ways than rolling your own TCP server. If C# is being the server, have a look at Embed.IO - adding a webserver to your app for relatively pain free "rest api controller" style "write a method, decorate it with [httpget] and chuck some json at it from the remote end" solve

Comment: @FlorianBecker You are not binding the `TcpClient` to a local IP/Port before connecting, so it will bind to a random IP/port, so you can't get that error from the `TcpClient`.  So it has to be coming from the `TcpListener`, and it can happen only when you try to listen on an IP/Port that is already in use by another socket. Again, verify this with `netstat`

Comment: @RemyLebeau netstat piped with grep on my port reveals only a process called Unix 3 that ist a stream connected to 693536 but not my port (3536)

Comment: @FlorianBecker there is simply no possible way you can get an "address already in use" error when the requested IP/port is not in use somewhere.

Comment: IDK I wish I would know the answer. It's haunting me but this is what I'm dealing with. Do you want more insights? Maybe I can share screenshots or try a different port

Comment: Edit: changed port to 353666. Still threw that exception

Comment: `353666` is not a valid port.

Comment: @akop I've tried many with less numbers but I think I might be onto something. I have a Thread.sleep on the main Thread. I don't know why but it seems to affect the connection. When I initialize both and instead of Thread.sleep I call while(!client.connected) client.Connect(address) it doesn't throw an error and tells me that it's connected

Comment: @FlorianBecker A single TCP connection already allows for two-way communication, you don't need to start two connections within one application. Which program is the host, and which is the client? You need one of the two applications to act as a host, and listen for incoming connections, and the other application acts as the client and connects to it. That's the difference between TcpListener (listens for incoming connections) and TcpClient (a single connection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong constructor.

> TcpClient(IPEndPoint)
> Initializes a new instance of the TcpClient class and binds it to the specified local endpoint.

What you probably want is this:

> TcpClient(String, Int32)
> Initializes a new instance of the TcpClient class and connects to the specified port on the specified host.

See [TcpClient constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient?view=net-6.0#constructors)

Some knowledge: A client needs a free port too. Normally it will binds to a random free port. For a local connection are two sockets required - one for the client and one for the server.